# Thread not exiting

Tags: python, multithreading

I am learning about Thread in Python and am trying to make a simple program, one that uses threads to grab a number off the Queue and print it.

I have the following code

```
import threading
from Queue import Queue

test_lock = threading.Lock()

tests = Queue()

def start_thread():
    while not tests.empty():
        with test_lock:
            if tests.empty():
                return
            test = tests.get()
        print("{}".format(test))

for i in range(10):
    tests.put(i)
threads = []
for i in range(5):
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=start_thread))
    threads[i].daemon = True
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
tests.join()
```

When run it just prints the values and never exits.

How do I make the program exit when the Queue is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docstring of `Queue.join()`:

> Blocks until all items in the Queue have been gotten and processed.
>
> The count of unfinished tasks goes up whenever an item is added to the
>   queue. The count goes down whenever a consumer thread calls task_done()
>   to indicate the item was retrieved and all work on it is complete.
>
> When the count of unfinished tasks drops to zero, join() unblocks.

So you must call `tests.task_done()` after processing the item.

Since your threads are daemon threads, and the queue will handle concurrent access correctly, you don't need to check if the queue is empty or use a lock. You can just do:

```
def start_thread():
    while True:
        test = tests.get()
        print("{}".format(test))
        tests.task_done()
```